# How can I achieve classic SSR like we used to do using Django/flask etc using SvelteKit?

Tags: javascript, server-side-rendering, sveltekit

[SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) is a very advanced modern framework which can generate

- [SSR (server-side rendering)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting)
- CSR (client-side rendering)
- SSG (static site generation)
- [SPA (single page application)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)
- MPA (multi page application)

But I just want simple classic `SSR` that we used to do using Django/flask etc. I don't want advanced features like [Hydration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydration_(web_development)).

How can I get classic `SSR` using `SvelteKit` which I can host on `AWS EC2` via `Nginx reverse proxy`?

**What is the point of this question?**
I have good understanding of classic SSR and I want to learn SvelteKit and modern features like Hydration. So I want to understand newly concept using my exsiting understanding. So just for learning and building understanding I want to try and observe.

Comment: What is the point of that? I.e. SSR is on by default, so why turn off client-side rendering?

Comment: Don't disable CSR and cripple Svelte's abilities, especially when learning. It will lead to unnecessary "why does it not work?" moments.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `export const csr = false`

In root `+layout.server.js` or root `+layout.js` will make app pure SSR like classic SSR.

Comment: This disables the whole JS on the client side. Is there any way to disable hydration alone for all pages and load JS like Google recaptcha v3, etc which needs JS